# MTG Perilous Reasearch and Improbable alliance, resolution of spell and triggered ability timing?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Perilous Research](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Perilous%20Research) has a comma and "then" in the text description. I am unclear whether this allows triggered abilities to be considered in the middle of the spell resolution. Specifically, if I control [Improbable Alliance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Improbable%20Alliance), when I cast Perilous Research and draw two cards, can I sacrifice the token that has just been created by the triggered ability of Improbable alliance??

Answer (score 2):

**No, whatever permanent you want to sacrifice to Perilous Research already has to be on the battlefield before it starts resolving.**

Improbable Alliance does trigger in the middle of Perilous Research's resolution, as soon as you draw the two cards and before you sacrifice a permanent. However, triggered abilities only enter the stack, let alone resolve, the next time a player would get priority. That only happens after Perilous Research has finished resolving, so you can't sacrifice the token that would be created on that specific Improbable Alliance trigger.

> 603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.

> 603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card **the next time a player would receive priority.**

> 117.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.

Comment: Don't know if it's even worth mentioning, but the bold summary sentence is correct for this question but not true as a general rule/principle. If in theory you had a replacement effect such as "whenever you would draw a card, instead create a food token", or something along those lines, then you would be able to sacrifice your new food token that didn't exist when Perilous Research started to resolve.